# Disabling Mobile horizontal scroll on Full width sections

Tags: html, css

I'm having slight issue with one of the sites that I'm developing. I decided to have few few full width sections on the website. Everything works fantastic on the mobile but I can't remove horizontal scroll on mobile which essentially is ruining the site.
I have tried few different approaches such as:
Adding the viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Adding max-width property to body and disabling overflow-x

```
body { max-width:100%; overflow-x:hidden;}
```

My full width section code looks like this:

```
.full-width-light {
    margin: 0 -9999rem;
    padding: 0.01rem 9999rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    color:$basegrey;
    background-color:$basewhite;
}
```

However when I addd extra max-width:100% to the element all child items inside go wobbly and are squeezed in a small area.

On the desktop however, everything works good and I don't have any issues with horizontal scroll what so ever.

My body has following properties assigned to it

```
body {
max-width:100%!important;
overflow-x:hidden!important;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: If you can provide a working demo of the issue you're experiencing, that would help immensely.

Comment: Hmm, the homepage is working fine on my iPhone... ooh, I see it now.

Comment: That's the problem. Website works fine but horizontal scroll is killing it. 
It does work in the dev tools as well.

Comment: It's the contact us section that's super-wide, dunno why yet.

Comment: When I remove all full width sections horizontal scroll vanishes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by removing

```
/* margin: 0 -9999rem; */
/* padding: 0.01rem 9999rem; */
```

And instead adding

```
margin:0 -6% 0 -6%;
```

Main wrapper class has width of 90% so removing the initial margins solved the issue.

Thanks for your answer Karl, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Going to throw this up as the cause of the issue (whether you can live with the "fix" or seek an alternative though...

I've reduced (deleted everything via Dev Tools) until I'm just left with the final .`hero-footer` div - the horizontal scroll remains.

Removing the margin / width settings (which seem just a little crazy on the values tbh) removes the horizontal scroll.

```
.full-width-dark {
    /* margin: 0 -9999rem; */
    /* padding: 0.01rem 9999rem; */
    color: #F5F5F5;
    background-color: #262626;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

There's enough classes around that to override the values just for that block.